# Comparar valores iguales en dos ArrayList java

Tags: java, arraylist

Si tengo dos `ArrayList` diferentes en mi código como puedo hacerle para ver que valores son iguales por ejemplo:

```
ArrayList a=new ArrayList();
a.add("Juan");
a.add("Pedro");
a.add("Luis");
ArrayList b=new ArrayList();
b.add("Carlos");
b.add("Luis");
b.add("Juan");
```

Quiero saber cuales nombres se repiten y en que posición están.

Comment: En base a los datos de tus ArrayList debes iterar para realizar una comparación de los valores, agregué respuesta, No olvides realizar el [tour] del sitio, saludos.

Answer (score -1):

Debes iterar los elementos de un ArrayList y comparar el contenido con los elementos del segundo ArrayList, si determinas que son iguales puede imprimir su posición.

```
for(int i = 0; i< a.size(); i++){ //Itera elementos del primer ArrayList
    for(int j = 0; j< b.size(); j++){//Itera elementos del segundo ArrayList
           if(a.get(i).equals(b.get(j))){ //Compara si los valores son iguales.
               System.out.println("Elemento del array a \"" + a.get(i) + "\", posición: " + i + "  es igual a el elemento del array b  en la posición: " + j);
           }
    }
}
```

En base a lo anterior y a los valores definidos en tu pregunta tendrías como salida:

> Elemento del array a "Juan", posición: 0  es igual a el elemento del
>   array b  en la posición: 2 Elemento del array a "Luis", posición: 2 
>   es igual a el elemento del array b  en la posición: 1

Comment: **CP 301 () Cuando se califique con -1, es bueno para el sitio se indique la razón**, esto para mejorar la pregunta, eliminarla o si existen argumentos platicar sobre el tema.